# remove multiple duplicate data records if only one of them meets a certain criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server

the core of this question is to know how I can filter out a specific data. To better explain I will create an example.

Let's say I have the following table:

| Id | Date | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-01-01 | 2 |
| 1 | 2023-01-02 | 3 |
| 1 | 2023-01-03 | 4 |
| 2 | 2023-01-01 | 2 |
| 2 | 2023-01-02 | 3 |
| 3 | 2023-01-01 | 2 |

At this case, I am only interest in the ids which have never been market as status = 4. I could filter out the third row by 'WHERE Status <> 4' but I would still be counting the first and second row. Which is something I am not looking for.

Basically, I am looking for a way to delete all the records of an ID that has been in a specific status (at this case, status = 4).

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

| Id | Date | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2023-01-01 | 2 |
| 2 | 2023-01-02 | 3 |
| 3 | 2023-01-01 | 2 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
select t.id,t.date,t.status
from your_table as t
where not exists
(
 select 1 from your_table as x
   where t.id=x.id and x.status=4
)
```

Comment: If it worked....then SOF etiquette is to "mark as the answer".. so this question stops coming up in "unanswered questions" filters.

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH CTE AS
(SELECT ID FROM sometable WHERE Status = 4)

DELETE FROM sometable WHERE ID IN
(SELECT ID FROM CTE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way you can try:

```
DELETE FROM DataTable WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM DataTable WHERE status = 4)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Community Bot, keep out of grown up discussions?

Answer (score 0):

This is an other way to do it using the window function `SUM()` combined with `CASE WHEN` to check if Status = 4 exist Per Id :

```
with cte as (
  select *, sum(case when Status = 4 then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by Id) as is_exist
  from mytable
)
select Id, Date, Status
from cte
where is_exist = 0;
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/rKHZqeqa)